# Savind data into a database in UsersController - CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I made a little application with users and tasks in CakePHP.
In case of delete users I dont want delete them, just change value in database where is column 'status' from '1' to '0'. I dont know how to do it.

Code of Users Controller (Delete) :

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($user['status'] == '1') {
        //Here should be code about change value
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read the book http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html  This sounds like you don't even know about the very basics of the framework, so I highly recommend you to do the tutorials to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have created model by following proper naming convention then you can try the code below.

```
public function delete($id = null) {
        $this->User->id = $id;
        if (!$this->User->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid user'));
        }
        if ($this->User->saveField('status', 0);) {
            $this->Flash->success(__('User deleted'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('User was not deleted'));
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function delete($id = null)
{
    $this->request->allowMethod(['post', 'delete']);
    $user = $this->Users->get($id);
    if ($user->status == 1) {
        $user->status = 0;
        $this->Users->save($user);
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been deleted.'));
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
    }

    return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
}
```